# can i include a file whose path is from a string variable?

Tags: c++, c++20

i think in python:

i can use:

```
def include_something(s):
  exec('import %s'%(s))
```

to import package dynamically

but in c++:

```
void include_something(const std::string& v) {
  # include v.c_str();
}
```

seems doestnt work.

So, is there any methods can do this? and will the futures c++ support this kind of function?

Comment: No, you can't. #include is a compile time directive (more precise, pre-compile time). `v.c_str()` is a runtime value. You can achieve something similar by loading shared libraries in runtime.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? any specific requirement?

Comment: Please, remember that Python is an interpreted language. Hence, such a construct is possible. C++ is a compiled language where compile time and runtime are distinct.

Comment: @Sourabh because i have a directory saves a lot of header(they are come from other people, and i need to include them all to load function)

Comment: @user15924460 then how does that make you think you need to include source code files at run time?

Answer (score 2):

**Simple answer**: No, You can't

**Answer with details**:
You can't do this with either `include` or `import`. As You can see on the picture below, `include` works on preprocess time, and `import` works on precompile time. While `c_str` is running at compile time (if it is `constexpr`), or at run time (if casual class or function), therefore, in any case, the import(or include) will be completed before the program learns the name of the module
[image: compilation process]
[source of image](https://www.esrlabs.com/journal/c++20-modules/)

Comment: "import works on precompile time" what do you mean by that? precompile is cpython optimization

Comment: Did you make this image? If not, could you please provide the source? I guess it's from an article and I want to read it.

Comment: @VolodymyrBoiko I haven't found any official information about exact moment, when modules works(but it's unambiguously before compilation), so in this case I shared info from another site(link under image)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in C/C++ to achieve dynamic header loading.

**BUT**

I'll do as the following:

**Create a simple PowerShell script** to create a master header file, that will contain all the headers from a given directory.

```html
$source_dir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0\um\alljoyn_c\"
$master_headerfile = 'master.h'

Remove-Item $master_headerfile

New-Item $master_headerfile -ItemType File -Value "// Master header file`n"

Get-ChildItem $source_dir -Filter *.h |
Foreach-Object {

    Add-Content $master_headerfile "#include `"$_`""

}
```

**Output will be**
[image]

**Now just include this `master.h` in your source file**.

I hope, it will help you.

Thanks :)